# Add some text after :" using sed?

Tags: sed, suricata

Can anyone help me create a script that adds `[ SURICATA ]` in this log file?

```
alert http $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"ET SCAN SQL Injection Attempt (Agent uil2pn)"; flow:to_server,established; content:"$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -i 's/.*:"/&[ SURICATA ]/' yourfile.log
```